# .NET Core configure OpenIddict with MongoDb

Tags: c#, mongodb, .net-core, openiddict

For my REST Api I want to use the OpenIddict authentication scheme. As database I am using MongoDb. I have installed all necessary dependencies. All dependencies have the newest version.

In my Startup.cs I want to register OpenIddict now. In the first step make this (like in the documentaion)

```cs
services.AddDbContext<UserDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseOpenIddict<ObjectId>();
});
```

Right on `options.UseOpenIddict<ObjectId>();` I get the following error:

```
'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseOpenIddict' and no accessible extension method 'UseOpenIddict' accepting a first argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

It's the `CS1061` error.

I am using all directives. I have googled a lot. The only thing I found was that you need to install the required packages, but I installed them. (In the solution files of the tutorial I am following are the exact same ones)

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: If you use MongoDB, why do you call `services.AddDbContext()`, which is an Entity Framework method? OpenIddict natively supports MongoDB: https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenIddict.MongoDb

Comment: @KévinChalet thank you. This helped a lot. I added my solution to my answer now

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Problem was with a package that overrode the `UseOpenIddict` method. I have uninstalled the package an rewrote some code, since the package wasn't that necessary. [This](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Primitives/2.0.0?_src=template) is the package that isn't compatible.

## Update

Thank you [Kévin Chalet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/542757/k%C3%A9vin-chalet) for [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62854050/asp-net-core-cant-register-openiddict-in-service-configuration-startup#comment111153135_62854050).

I rewrote my identity configuration to

```cs
services.AddIdentityMongoDbProvider<UserEntity, UserRoleEntity>(mongo =>
{
    mongo.ConnectionString = _databaseUri;
});
```

This works now perfectly for me.

## Update 2

I have googled some more and I haven't found any solutions on how to properly implement OpenIddict and MongoDb. For someone who is just starting the following might help. My OpenIddict / authentication / authorization runs fine with the following configuration:

#### Startup.cs

ConfigureServices:

```cs
services.AddIdentityMongoDbProvider<UserEntity, UserRoleEntity>(mongo = >{
    mongo.ConnectionString = _databaseUri;
});

services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options = >{
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserNameClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Name;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.UserIdClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Subject;
    options.ClaimsIdentity.RoleClaimType = OpenIdConnectConstants.Claims.Role;
});

services.AddAuthentication(options = >{
    options.DefaultScheme = OpenIddictValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});

services
    .AddOpenIddict()
    .AddCore(options = >{
        options.UseMongoDb()
            .UseDatabase(new MongoClient(_databaseUri)
            .GetDatabase(_database));
    }).AddServer(options = >{
        options.SetAccessTokenLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(5));
    
        options.UseMvc();
    
        options.EnableTokenEndpoint("/api/token");
    
        options.EnableUserinfoEndpoint("/api/userinfo");
    
        options.AllowPasswordFlow()
            .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();
    
        options.AcceptAnonymousClients();
    }).AddValidation();

services.AddAuthorization(options = >{
    options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                .AddAuthenticationSchemes(OpenIddictValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                .Build();
});
```

Configure:

```cs
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseCors("AllowBrowserApp");

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthorization();
```

Note: It is important where you register the authentication and authorization. The authentication comes before `app.UseRouting()` and the authorization after that. Otherwise it won't work. If you use Visual Studio it will show you.

#### UserEntity.cs

```cs
public class UserEntity : MongoUser
{
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    public string Lastname { get; set; }
}
```

You can add more properties if you want.

#### UserRoleEntity.cs

```cs
public class UserRoleEntity : MongoRole
{
    public UserRoleEntity() : base() { }

    public UserRoleEntity(string roleName) : base(roleName) { }
}
```

Comment: I'm assuming you're using this [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AspNetCore.Identity.Mongo/) for `AddIdentityMongoDbProvider`?

Comment: @MarkMalabanan yes I am